# ssl pending validation from namecheap with cname method in route53 aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-route53, namecheap

Hey guys i want to enable my ssl certificate in namecheap with cname method, i get this info
[image]

According to doc, i'm using route53 from aws to add my cname records, and i created a cname record in my hosted zone like this:

[image]

however my ssl certificate is still pending.

i was checking in https://mxtoolbox.com/CNAMELookup.aspx with the host/recordname value and i get this info:

[image]

what am i missing to get my ssl certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify - you are not using AWS Certificate Manager right?

Comment: yes correct, i'm not using AWS Certificate Manager, i'm using namecheap to generate the SSL cerrtificate. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you created a Route53 public hosted zone for your domain, but you haven't actually connected that public hosted zone to your domain registrar, so DNS queries for your domain are not being served by Route53 yet.

Comment: thanks @MarkB i just followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2J9Q4AlwM4 to configure namecheap with route53, that's why you see A/NS,SOA records in the picture too :).Thanks!

Comment: The NS records in the Route53 picture will always be there. Your picture of that doesn't prove you did anything. You have to configure your domain name registrar (Namecheap in this instance I suppose) with those NS records that Route53 provided, in order for Route53 to be the authoritative DNS host for your domain. You didn't modify the default Route53 NS records did you?

Comment: These discussions are beside the point as the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be closed as such. Questions here must be about programming. See the [help/on-topic] discussion.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB i was able to enable the ssl in namecheap. The missing step was adding a CNAME with the same host/value in namecheap. Thank you again!

Comment: @ntj34 if adding a CNAME in Namecheap worked, then you are actually using Namecheap for your DNS, and you aren't actually using Route53 at all.